# selenium firefox webdriver - accessing session

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am already logged in to my googlemail account in Firefox browser with profile named: test_profile. 
Using Selenium,  I launch Firefox browser with profile test_profile, but I am seeing login page. Meaning, the session/cookies are not being used.

What am I doing wrong? Or what can be done so I can use my session.

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("test_profile");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("https://www.googlemail.com");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure loading the FF profile will transfer *session* cookies because session cookies are stored in memory and destroyed when the browser session is closed (meaning they should not be written to the file system).  Why not use Selenium to do the login, then the cookies will be there for the Selenium browser session?

Comment: Thanks xDaevax. I am pretty sure that google is persisting login cookies. When I close my browser and manually open it, I am not asked to login and my session gets restored. I am trying to achieve that same. Also, I tried loggin in using Selenium, which works - but when I try to run the test again, the login session/cookies are lost and I need to re login.

Comment: Interesting.  Well the URL googlemail.com redirects to mail.google.com, have you tried going directly to mail.google.com or gmail.com ?

Comment: Good point. Yes, I tried directly mail.google.com - not working.